# Janela de edição código fecha mesmo ao cancelar o fechamento

Tags: bug, status-pronto

## Reproduzindo o problema

No formulário de resposta de uma questão qualquer...

1. Clique no botão **`trecho de código`** ou pressione <kbd>CTRL+M</kbd>
2. Clique no **`X`** do canto superior direito para fechar a janela
3. Clique em **`OK`** para fechar a janela
4. Repita os passos **#1** e **#2**
5. Clique em **`Cancelar`** e ***a janela ainda será fechada***

Nota: o mesmo ocorre se pressionar <kbd>ESC</kbd> para fechar a janela.

## Ambiente

O erro foi reproduzido no Chrome (última versão) e Internet Explorer 10, com ou sem login.

Comment: A pergunta que fica é como chegaste a isso? :D

Comment: Perdi um grande trecho de código ontem. Se não me engano,  pressionei `ESC` sem querer e *puff!!!* Perdi tudo. Agora é pessoal! ;)

Comment: Postagem no "metão": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247450/snippet-editor-window-closes-even-when-the-closing-confirmation-dialog-is-cancel

Comment: fixed in build 2015.1.22.2213, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247458/156631 for details